# Is a finite cyclic group a Poincare duality group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cyclic-groups, duality-theorems, classifying-spaces

I am trying to understand whether the finite cyclic group of order $n$, $C_n$ is a Poincare duality group, i.e. whether it's classifying space $K(C_n,\,1)$ is a Poincare complex. I know that the classifying space of a cyclic group is a lens space, but am unsure whether a lens space is necessarily a Poincare complex.

Comment: As far as I know, for a Poincare duality group,G, there is a finite length projective resolution of Z by ZG modules. If G is cyclic, then any projective resolution of Z is infinite. The classifying spaces for cyclic groups are not finite dimensional manifolds. For instance, the classifying space for Z/2Z is the infinite real projective space.

Answer (score 2):

No. A Poincaré duality space must in particular have vanishing cohomology above some degree, but a nontrivial finite cyclic group has nonvanishing cohomology in arbitrarily high degrees.